# Pyplot doesn't use the full space on 2D plots when setting equal ratio

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting some 2D fields using `matplotlib` and the fields have to be seen with equal aspect ratio. But when I set the aspect ratio I find that there are unnecessary blank spaces. Please consider the following example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt                                                                               
import numpy as np
x=np.arange(100)                                                                                                       
y=np.arange(100)                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Y, X = np.meshgrid(y,x)                                                                                                
Z = X + Y                                                                                                              
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z)                                                                                                  
#plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')                                                                             
plt.tight_layout()                                                                                                     
plt.colorbar()       
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

If I run that command I get this figure:

[image]

However, let's say I uncomment the line that sets the equal ratio . So let's say I include this:

```
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
```

I get the following output:

[image]

Which is a very poor use of space. I can't make the actual plot take better advantage of the figure space no matter how hard I try (I don't have that much knowledge of `pyplot`).

I there a way to expand the actual data part of the equal-ratio plot so that I have less white space?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having is caused by `"datalim"`, which asks the axes to apply the usual limits you would expect from a normal line or scatter plot, e.g. the use of 5% margin on each side of the shown data.

I do not see any reason to use `"datalim"` here. So you may just leave it out,

```
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
```

and get a plot with equal aspect and no white space around.

Comment: Thanks for the very simple answer. I misunderstood what `datalim` did when reading the docs!